# Why the UIApplicationMain function is named as the class naming style

Tags: ios, swift, cocoa-touch, uikit, program-entry-point

When I first saw the [UIApplicationMain](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/1622933-uiapplicationmain?language=objc) I though it was a class, because the initial letter of the name is written in upper case. While when reading the documents it turns out that it is a function. Any particular reasons that Apple has to names the **UIApplicationMain** function in the class naming style?

Comment: `UI` is the prefix for the UIKit framework. – All Cocoa functions (not methods) have the (uppercase) prefix for the framework: https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CodingGuidelines/Articles/NamingBasics.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20001281-BBCHBFAH, https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CodingGuidelines/Articles/NamingFunctions.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20001283-BAJGGCAD

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From [Naming Functions](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CodingGuidelines/Articles/NamingFunctions.html) in the
"Coding Guidelines for Cocoa" (emphasis added):

> Function names are formed like method names, but with a couple exceptions:
>
> - They start with the **same prefix** that you use for classes and constants.
> - The first letter of the word after the prefix is capitalised.

Here, `UI` is the prefix for the UIKit framework.